# JavaFX & ControlsFX - Autocomplete TextField - show drop down menu

Tags: java, javafx, drop-down-menu, textfield, controlsfx

I'm using the ControlsFX library to create an AutoComplete Textfield for my JavaFX application. The autocomplete function works, but the problem is that I have to type at least 1 letter (and delete it after), so I can see the drop down menu with all the possible suggestions.
Is there any way to show the drop down menu of this AutoComplete TextField, just by clicking it?

This is my current code:

`TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(cityTextField, citiesList);`

Thank you!

Comment: doesn't the returned completionBinding has some api to show the popup? Anyway, it's opensource, look at how it's done and extend as needed :) And please stick to java naming conventions when showing code publicly ..

Comment: thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Solved using what you suggested, @kleopatra, thanks!